# Integrated Webcam not detected on an Alienware M17x R3 for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, webcam, alienware

I have an Alienware M17x R3.  I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I know the webcam was working before.  I pressed `FN + F9` Which is shown as a camera key but the camera is not detected on any apps (cheese, zoom, etc.)

I typed in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0955:7002 NVIDIA Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 187c:0520 Alienware Corporation 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I typed in `dmesg`:

```
[ 3786.350637] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
[ 3786.350645] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
[ 3786.365473] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
[ 3786.365479] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
[ 3786.629781] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[ 3786.662475] usb 2-1.3: config 247 has too many interfaces: 120, using maximum allowed: 32
[ 3786.662482] usb 2-1.3: config 247 descriptor has 1 excess byte, ignoring
[ 3786.662487] usb 2-1.3: config 247 has 0 interfaces, different from the descriptor's value: 120
[ 3786.663978] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05ca, idProduct=181a, bcdDevice= c.16
[ 3786.663984] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3786.663988] usb 2-1.3: Product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_3M
[ 3786.663992] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: CN0PYVWX72487114009FA00
[ 3786.664575] usb 2-1.3: can't set config #247, error -32
[ 3788.757961] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
[ 3788.757969] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
[ 3788.767442] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0xab on isa0060/serio0).
[ 3788.767448] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e02b <keycode>' to make it known.
[ 3788.966649] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 12
```

I typed in `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 780M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
0d:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
13:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
13:00.1 SD Host controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
19:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

I can see from `dmesg` it says the keypress <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> tried to activate the camera AND that it's USB (it seems) even though it's "integrated". However nothing happens. As you can see from `dmesg` it said that the USB disconnected for the device.

I cannot turn it on via BIOS.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question to help anyone else running into this issue.  It turns out the messages from `dmesg` were correct.  It turned on the camera, however after you see that it's turned on via `dmesg`, at least for me, I had to reboot the machine.  I am certain there's a command that establishes the use of the camera with Ubuntu without a reboot but I don't know it and maybe someone here can help with that.

Anyways, if everyone else is having issues and not able to get it working with FN + Camera (for me it was F9, some have F10), then reboot it after it's recognized on `dmesg`

Comment: Rebooting after changing configuration is sometimes necessary.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks